# How to comment 20 lines of Python code on vim?

Tags: vim

How to comment 20 lines of code at a time from a python file in `vi`/`vim`.

What command can I use instead of using `#` or `"""` ??

Comment: what code editor are you using?

Comment: Every IDE has its own shortcut to do it.

Comment: i want to edit py file on only linux server using vi editor

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120615/how-to-comment-multiple-lines-at-once

Comment: You should edit your question and add that.

Answer (score 6):

What I typically do is this:

1. Leave editing mode <kbd>Esc</kbd>, may need to hit couple times
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to enter "Visual" mode
3. Highlight the desired lines via arrow keys, or use <kbd>3j</kbd> to select 3 lines down or <kbd>3k</kbd> 3 lines up
4. Enter command mode via <kbd>:</kbd>, and when you see `:'<,'>` displayed type in `s/^/#/`, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This is visual approach, sort of like using a mouse in GUI to highlight lines, except without a mouse in vim

Answer (score 5):

In `vi`:

- navigate to the line where you wish to start commenting out
- enter command mode (<kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd>)
- type `.,+20s/^/#/` or `.,+20s/^/"""/` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Python IDE (As PyCharm) you can select these lines and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (or the default "comment" shortcut) to comment them.

If you are using a common text editor either you have to comment line per line or use the multi-line string (triple quotes) as a multi-line comment.

Comment: i am working linux server,
i want to edit py file on only linux server using vi editor

Comment: The second solution proposed should work.

Comment: @cojapysp also you could either download the remote file open it in the IDE edit it then overwite the file to the remote machine. of if the IDE permits it, open the remote file in it dirrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Vim can comment and uncomment multiple lines at once for specific lines range. Kindly check below example. here we will comment and uncomment from line numbers 7 to 13.
Open file in vim

```
#vim /etc/hosts
```

run below two commands one by one

```
:se nu
:7,13s/^/#
```

done.
for uncomment, run below one command

```
:7,13s/^#//
```